# have a boolean that must be set to 0 rather than false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an Item object that has a boolean value called has_instore_image that when set in a before_save method must be set to 0 rather than false. Is there a reason why this is so? Is this the expected behavior? I'm using Rails 3.2.19.

code:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :has_instore_image

  before_save :set_has_instore_image

  def set_has_instore_image
    if self.instore_images.count>0
      self.has_instore_image=true
    else
      self.has_instore_image=0
      #self.has_instore_image=false
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Rails docs on callbacks:

```
If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled.
```

So what happens is that, as the last expression of your callback evaluates to `false`, then the callback chain is stopped and the `save` action fails.

You can remedy it like this:

```
def set_has_instore_image
  if self.instore_images.count>0
    self.has_instore_image=true
  else      
    self.has_instore_image=false
  end
  true
end
```

In fact, it's considered good practice to end all your `before_*`callback definitions returning `true` to avoid this very same problem.